# Dropdown disabled/enabled not working except IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In my application there are two dropdowns. Based on value selected in one dropdown the other dropdown(Whole div in which dropdown present) is disabled/enabled. But the other dropdown is present in another div. My problem is this is working fine in IE but not in any other browsers such as Firefox,Chrome

```
     function rrf(id) {
        if (id == 1 || id == 9) {
            $("#IdDiv").children().prop('disabled', true);
           }
        else {
            $("#IdDiv").children().prop('disabled', false);
         }
    }



 $('select[name="DDl1"]').change(function () {
           var idf = $(this).val();
            rrf(idf);
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

Actually the two dropdowns are dropdownlists in mvc.
After rendering, second dropdown list was converted to a div Like below

```
 <div id="IdDiv" class="select2-container span4">
 <a class="select2-choice" onclick="return false;" href="#">
   <span>-- SELECT --</span>
   <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"></abbr>
   <div>
      <b></b>
   </div>
</a>
<div class="select2-drop select2-offscreen">
  <div class="select2-search">
    <input class="select2-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
  </div>
  <ul class="select2-results"> </ul>
</div>

<select id="DDl2" class="span4" name="DDl2" style="display: none;">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="DDl2"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle with ur code?

Comment: @iBlue see Updated Question once..

Comment: Your `DDl2` is outside of the div that you're trying to set all children to disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#IdDiv").children().attr('disabled', 'disabled')` to disable and use `$("#IdDiv").children().removeAttr('disabled')` to enable.

It will work....